# Storing original values for IIFEs in watch function (reset filters) in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, watch

I have a bunch of filters and I seek to write a function so that on ng-click all filters are reset to the original values.
However, all my filter

For example,I have a filter for number of stops which all works fine.

```
$filter('stopsFilter')($scope.data)(stopsObject);
```

Data is obtained by http request. I have a $watch function on data to update the view based on data of course. Within the watch function there is stopsObject so that I updates itself as well based on $scope.data. Since stopsObject strictly depends on the structure of $scope.data, there not proper way to define stopsObject beforehand (expect setting it empty).

```
      $scope.stopsObject = { //happens in the watch function of $scope.data
        "allCars": $scope.selectall,
        "allElements": $scope.checkedStops,
        "singleElements": $scope.stopsPerLeg
      };
```

$scope.stopsPerLEg and checkedStops are again IIFEs within the watch function. Whenever I update the allElements, the entire stopsObject updates.

But to write a reset function for all my filters

```
         $scope.allFilters = {
            stopsObject:$scope.stopsObject,
          };

$scope.resetFilter = function() {

            $scope.stopsObject=$scope.allFilters.stopsObject;

          };
```

This does not work as stopsObject is updates constantly. How can I set the original calculated $scope.stopsObject into my allFilters object. I basically need the value that is calculated right after the HTTP request is finished.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just do a angular.copy such as

```
$scope.allFilters=angular.copy({...})
```

it works perfectly.